# Dot Net Framework for cefsharp 71.0.2

Tags: .net, cefsharp

Just to confirm once , Can I use .Net Framework 4.6.1 for cefsharp 71.0.2. Or I have to target to .NetFramework 4.5.2 only ?

Answer (score 0):

.Net 4.5.2 is the minimum required version, you can target a higher version of the framework.